# Trying to capture the result of a select query into a variable but getting syntax errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code I'm using is:

```
DECLARE @var1 AS int;
SET @var1=8191;
WITH A AS (
    SELECT 0 AS ORD, @var1 AS NUMBER, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS BITS
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ORD+1, NUMBER/2,  CAST(BITS+CAST(NUMBER%2 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS VARCHAR(20))
          FROM A
          WHERE  NUMBER>0)
SELECT RIGHT('000000000000000'+ CASE WHEN BITS='' THEN '0' ELSE REVERSE(BITS) END,16) AS BIN_VALUE 
FROM A
WHERE NUMBER=0
```

This gets the binary value of the number stored in @Var1 so for 8191 it would give the result 0001111111111111, I want to capture that number so I can use it in another query for example in @Var2. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
SELECT @var2 = RIGHT('000000000000000'+ CASE WHEN BITS='' THEN '0' ELSE REVERSE(BITS) END,16) 
FROM A
WHERE NUMBER = 0;
```

Comment: That works great, Thank you. I was using SET instead of select and that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

Try this...I added the `Declare @Var2` and in the final select I added the `SELECT @Var2 =` bit.

```
DECLARE @Var2 AS VARCHAR(50) -- or whatever data type you need

DECLARE @var1 AS int;    
SET @var1=8191;
WITH A AS (
SELECT 0 AS ORD, @var1 AS NUMBER, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS BITS
UNION ALL
SELECT ORD+1, NUMBER/2,  CAST(BITS+CAST(NUMBER%2 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS VARCHAR(20))
      FROM A
      WHERE  NUMBER>0)
SELECT @Var2 = RIGHT('000000000000000'+ CASE WHEN BITS='' THEN '0' ELSE     REVERSE(BITS) END,16) AS BIN_VALUE 
FROM A
WHERE NUMBER=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way without the recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @var1 AS SMALLINT = 8191,
        @Var2 CHAR(16);

SELECT @Var2 = 
RIGHT('000000000000000'+ 
 REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                 FORMAT(@var1,'x')
                ,'0','0000')
               ,'1','0001')
              ,'2','0010')
             ,'3','0011')
            ,'4','0100')
           ,'5','0101')
          ,'6','0110')
         ,'7','0111')
        ,'8','1000')
       ,'9','1001')
      ,'a','1010')
     ,'b','1011')
    ,'c','1100')
   ,'d','1101')
  ,'e','1110')
 ,'f','1111')
,16)

SELECT @Var2
```